# How to alert on load in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I can't seem to make an alert work properly in ejs. Basically I want an alert to appear when the page is loaded and visible but I just can't make it happen. I've dug through Stack and tried different many things with JS and jQuery but all they do is alert before page is visible and I have a blank white screen with an alert and after OK is clicked the page becomes visible. I'm testing it in Opera.

Maybe it's not just scripts and I am missing something?

PS. window.onload function seems to work fine with an ordinary html file but alert shows before some of css is loaded. Just testing. Found it peculiar.

PS. Okay, now it seems really strange. Apparently, the page actually loads but I don't see it refresh. If I refresh the page, I see the alert but the page is blank. But if I minimize the browser and then put it back on, the page is there. What is going on? [Video](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/YoKjR-7FUcCiaA)

```
    <%- include('partials/header'); -%>
    
    <body>
    
      <script>
        window.onload = () =>{
            alert("fully loaded");
        }
      </script>
    
    <div id="formDiv" class="flexbox-container">
      <form action="/addword" method="post" class="ml-auto mr-auto mt-auto mb-auto" id="wordaddFrom" required>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wordInput" name="wordInput" placeholder="Word" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="defInput" name="defInput" placeholder="Definition" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exInput" name="exInput" placeholder="Example" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="defInput" name="titleInput" placeholder="Title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name=genreInput placeholder="Genre">
     <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Genre</option>
      <option>Games</option>
      <option>Movies</option>
      <option>Books</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    
    <%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

```
app.get("/addword", function(req, res) {

res.render("addword");

});

app.post("/addword", function(req, res){

  var newWord = new Dicword ({

    word: req.body.wordInput,
    definition: req.body.defInput,
    title: req.body.titleInput,
    genre: req.body.genreInput,
    example: req.body.exInput
  });


  Dicword.exists({word: req.body.wordInput}, (function(err, existingDoc){

if (existingDoc === null) {

  newWord.save(function(err){
    if (!err){
      console.log("add succ");
      res.render("addwordSUCC");
    }

    else {console.log(err);}
  });
} else {

let exists = "This word already exists"
res.render("addwordFAIL", {exists: exists});
}


}));
```

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: I don't see why the downvotes since there's no solution for this on stack. Crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window.onload function only run when the page is loaded and setTimeout function will wait the css is loaded.

You can try

```
window.onload = () =>{
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("fully loaded");
    }, 500);
}
```

or

```
let everythingLoaded = setInterval(function() {
  if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
    clearInterval(everythingLoaded);
    init(); // this is the function that gets called when everything is loaded
  }
}, 10);

function init() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => { 
  // When window loaded ( external resources are loaded too- `css`,`src`, etc...) 
  if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
     init();
  }
})

function init() {
  alert('Hello World');
}
```

or In Opera and Safari is same as before but Only change is I nested the alert code in setTimeout function.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => { 
  // When window loaded ( external resources are loaded too- `css`,`src`, etc...) 
  if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
     init();
  }
})

function init() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Hello World');
   }, 100);
}
```

[Solution Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nbHEAgfQJujgUa8xiHObCs1xyjTWkamX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i think I tried that. Do I put it in the head or body? I just tried accessing this page with an iphone and it's the same. I see a blank page with an alert and only after okeing it i see the page.

Comment: @magrega I suggest to put the code in the end of body.

Comment: yeah, it seems to work but it feels like a workaround. I'd like to get to the bottom of it and understand why it works like that.

Comment: @magrega Which browser you are using?

Comment: Opera. And I tried safari on iOS 15.

Comment: @magrega Please try last solution It work or not?

Comment: I tried it before but I tried it again. It doesn't work they I want it too. It shows the alert but the page is white. But if I don't click OK and just minimize the browser and pull it back - the page is there under the alert.

Comment: I added a link to the video in the topic, maybe you could take a look?

Comment: @magrega I have watched your video. Now I understand your Problem. I have added a link to video of solution. Please watch my video.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't open the  link. Says err_connection_reset. Do you mind sharing it from another source?

Comment: @magrega I have updated the Link. Please check.

Comment: I've watched it. Thanks. Seems like the same workaround with delaying the alert. I guess this is going to be the answer for now.